# How to delete all events from Google calendar from specified date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-calendar-api

I'm using [googlecalendar plugin](https://github.com/francisoud/googlecalendar) for working with Google Calendar with ruby.

The only problem I'm facing is with deleting an event from google calendar.

I found an example to delete event in above mentioned github. But we need to pass event id. How can I use the below code to delete all events from google calendar from specified date?

**CODE:**

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../shared.rb'

g = GData.new
puts 'login'
token = g.login('REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_MAIL@gmail.com', 'REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PASSWORD')
puts "token: #{token}"

event = {:title=>'title',
          :content=>'content',
          :author=>'pub.cog',
          :email=>'pub.cog@gmail.com',
          :where=>'Toulouse,France',
          :startTime=>'2009-06-20T15:00:00.000Z',
          :endTime=>'2009-06-20T17:00:00.000Z'}

create_response = g.new_event(event)
puts create_response.body


puts 'delete_event'
# TODO GET id from new_event response
id='http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full/pgvgjdnh43g3bo0emnpfg0gnr4'
response = g.delete_event(id)
puts 'done'
```

**URL:**

https://github.com/francisoud/googlecalendar/blob/master/googlecalendar/examples/ruby_standalone/gdata_delete_event.rb

Please share your thoughts if we can do this with other plugins.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A search on github brought up this [google_calendar gem](https://github.com/northworld/google_calendar/blob/master/lib/google/event.rb) that seems to be the more popular gem (if not the standard). It is also better documented and organized.

This is what I came up with:

```
require 'google_calendar'

cal = Google::Calendar.new(:username => 'username@gmail.com', 
               :password => 'password',
               :app_name => 'delete_events')

cal.events.each { |event|
  event.delete if Time.parse(event.start_time) >= Time.new(2011,10,14)
}
```

Time.parse puts each event's start time into a format ruby can understand and then compares it to your given date October 14, 2011. If the event is on or after the event, it is deleted. To delete events before do:

```
 if Time.parse(event.start_time) <= Time.new(2011,10,14)
```

or for all events on a certain date do:

```
 if Time.parse(event.start_time) == Time.new(2011,10,14)
```